# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.postgresql.util.PGobject cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable; inside UUIDconverter

Tags: java, postgresql

I am trying to debug an existing code written by someone where one of the API is throwing the below exception

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.postgresql.util.PGobject cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.postgresql.util.PGobject cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

On debugging I found that the error is thrown during a GET call from JPA. There is UUID field in the model class that has a converter as below:

```
 @Id
  @Convert(converter = UUIDConverter.class)
  @Column(name = "ID", columnDefinition = "uuid")
  private UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
```

UUIDConverter class implementation:

```
@Converter
public class UUIDConverter<T> implements AttributeConverter<T, Object> {
    @Override
    public Object convertToDatabaseColumn(T objectValue) {
        try {
            PGobject out = new PGobject();
            out.setType("uuid");
            
            if(objectValue !=null && objectValue instanceof UUID) {
                out.setValue(objectValue.toString());
            } 
            
            return out;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to serialize to json field ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

On Analyzing the stack trace, found that the converter class calls a class CommitManager (org\eclipse\persistence\internal\sessions) sort method. This sort method in turn uses TreeMap. And it is this TreeMap's compare method that is throwing this exception.

Absolutely clueless about how to solve this. Did not find a lot of information on web. Please help.

Also I have tried with different versions of org.postgressql - 42.0.0(oldest compatible), 42.2.18(latest), 42.2.2. But no luck

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. In case you found no solution this here might help:
In the converter class simply implement a static nested class like this:

```
   static class CompareablePGobject extends PGobject implements Comparable<CompareablePGObject> {
        @Override
        public int compareTo(CompareablePGObject o) {
            return getValue().compareTo(o.getValue());
        }
    }
```

Then in the convertToDatabaseColumn method simply instantiate CompareablePGobject instead of PGobject.